# How to reach data from Intent in Android

Tags: java, android

i need to take data from intent. It works in onCreate method, but it doesn't work in Home class, which is bellow the onCreate method. I get this error: Can anyone help me, how i can fix this? To resolve: voznja_id works in oncreate method, but it doesn't work in Async Task class named Home. THANKS

```
**Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter value**
       @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            username = extras.getString("username");
            password = extras.getString("password");
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            voznja = (Voznja) intent.getSerializableExtra("voznja");
            System.out.println(voznja.getId())//ID = 118 it works
}
 public class Home extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .build();
            MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
            RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add("voznja_id", voznja.getId())// IT'S NULL HERE
                    .build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://www.autotrack.rs/android_juzna_backa/get_voznja.php?"
                    .method("POST", body)
                    .build();
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
//                System.out.println(response.body().string());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "";
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            try {
                System.out.println(voznja.getId());
                String rezultat = response.body().string();
                //System.out.println(rezultat);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Type type = new TypeToken<Data>() {
                }.getType();
                Data data = gson.fromJson(rezultat, type);
                // System.out.println(model);//
                //listaVoznjiAL.add(data.data);
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Intent i = new Intent(Unos.this, Landing.class);
                i.putExtra("data",data);
                i.putExtra("voznja", voznja);
                i.putExtra("username", username);
                i.putExtra("password", password);
                startActivity(i);
            } catch (Exception m) {
                m.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: please add the error to your question

Comment: **Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter value** @HamidSj voznja.getId() is null in class named Home.

Comment: where are you executing the `Home` class?

Comment: In Bottom Navigation View, like this.
                        new Unos.Home().execute();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is because `Home` is `ASyncTask` class and it's running in the background when the `voznja` object is not initialized yet.
you can pass the id of voznja through the parameters of `Home` class constructor like this:

```java
public class Home extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private voznjaId;
        public Home(int voznjaId){
            this.voznjaId = voznjaId;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .build();
            MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
            RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add("voznja_id", voznjaId)
                    .build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://www.autotrack.rs/android_juzna_backa/get_voznja.php?"
                    .method("POST", body)
                    .build();
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
//                System.out.println(response.body().string());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "";
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            try {
                System.out.println(voznja.getId());
                String rezultat = response.body().string();
                //System.out.println(rezultat);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Type type = new TypeToken<Data>() {
                }.getType();
                Data data = gson.fromJson(rezultat, type);
                // System.out.println(model);//
                //listaVoznjiAL.add(data.data);
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Intent i = new Intent(Unos.this, Landing.class);
                i.putExtra("data",data);
                i.putExtra("voznja", voznja);
                i.putExtra("username", username);
                i.putExtra("password", password);
                startActivity(i);
            } catch (Exception m) {
                m.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: @NikolaStankovic why it does not work? how did you use that?